# Stack got overwrite

Tags: java, stack

I'm writing a program which make a tree of node, and find it on dfs (not done yet), but i got a problem when i try to push a new node in to class. The new node overwrite the old node with my method. Node class declare like that

```
public class Node {
    int[][] matrix;
    Node pre;
    boolean visited;
}
```

and class dfs like this:(in shortage with only code got bug)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class DFS {
    private static Stack<Node> stack;
    public DFS()
    {
        stack = new Stack<Node>();
    }
    public static int dfs(int matrix[][])
    {
        Node first = new Node();
        first.matrix= matrix;
        first.visited=true;
        first.pre= null;
        stack.push(first);
        pushleft(stack.peek());
        pushleft(stack.peek());
        return 0;

    }
    public static void pushleft(Node Nodeleft)
    {
        Node Newnode= new Node();
        Newnode.matrix = left(Nodeleft.matrix);
        stack.push(Newnode);
    }
    public static int[][] left (int matrix[][]) {
    int matrix1[][]= new int[4][4];
    for(int i=0; i<=3;i++)
        for (int j=3;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] !=0) 
            {
                for (int k=j; k>=0; k--)
                    if (matrix[i][k]==0)
                    {       
                        for (int l=k; l<=2;l++) 
                            matrix1[i][l]=matrix[i][l+1];    
                        matrix1[i][3]=0;
                    }
                break;
            }

        }

    for(int i=0; i<=3;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {

            if (matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][j+1])  
            {
                matrix1[i][j]=matrix[i][j]*2;
                for (int l=j+1; l<=2;l++) 
                    matrix1[i][l]=matrix[i][l+1];    
                matrix1[i][3]=0;             
            }

        }
    return matrix1;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        stack = new Stack<Node>();
        int a[][]=new int[4][4];
        int goal;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input 4x4");
        for(int i=0; i<=3;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<=3;j++)
            {
                a[i][j]=in.nextInt();
            }
        if (dfs(a)==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Win");
            System.out.println("Cac trang thai:");
        while (!stack.isEmpty())
        {
        for(int i=0; i<=3;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<=3;j++)
            {               
                System.out.print(stack.peek().matrix[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        stack.pop();
        }

        in.close();
        }

    }
    }
```

When i try to in put this array

```
0 0 0 0
2 2 2 2
0 0 0 2
2 2 4 4
I want my output like this:<br/>
0 0 0 0 
8 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0 
4 8 0 0 

0 0 0 0 
4 4 0 0 
2 0 0 0 
4 8 0 0 

0 0 0 0
2 2 2 2
0 0 0 2
2 2 4 4
```

but it just print 3 times this:

```
0 0 0 0 
8 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0 
4 8 0 0
```

I guess my method pushleft got problem with static or something like that but still can't fix it. Can someone help?

Comment: i think your array object's are copying from one node to other that is why you are getting same matrix three time.

Comment: Yes. But can i tell me where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create every time new `Matrix` while you are calling `pushleft`.

You are getting issue because all the `Matrix Arrays` are pointing to same `object`.
so if you change anything in one `matrix` it will change in all the `matrix` of other `Node object` also.

Create new `Matrix` array and assign values from `old matrix array`.

as

```
 public static int[][] left (int matrix[][]) {
        int matrix2[][] = new int[4][4];
        // assign all the values as you want
        // your code...

       return matrix2;
   }
```

Comment: i don't understand what you said. Can you say this clearly? about this: "create every time new Matrix". and "Create new Matrix array and assign values from old matrix array." Thank you

Comment: i mean to say in `left` method create new array and assign the values from Matrix

Comment: I tried to do this. but is still not work. I think its about static method or something about stack.

Comment: @PhoenixRg checknow!! added what you need to change

Comment: i edited my post as your suggest. But it still not change. Or i did it wrong?

Comment: @PhoenixRg You can create as many arrays as you like, that won't change anything if you write `matrix1= matrix;`. After that line `matrix1` again refers to the array of `matrix` and if you alters its values, then you also change the values of `matrix`. That is why every output looks the same.

Comment: @Prashant What was the purpose of your change in his question?

Comment: @Tom he changed because i said to create new array but he was doing wrong so i updated his code!!

Comment: so this code matrix1= matrix; make matrix change when matrix1 change? And in contrast? Did matrix1 change when matrix change? Can u tell me where i can read more about this?

Comment: @Prashant Updates in the question shouldn't contain any kind of an answer. If he did something wrong, then you should add that to your question, instead of manipulating the question. If you "rolled back" his edit to the former question, then it is something different.

Comment: @Tom : i got your point . but i added my answer accordingly he changed his code and asked s i changed. otherwise i didn't have any intention to do that.